# I am getting an error of "object arrays are not supported" when i am fitting the Dynamic Factor Model under statsmodels package

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit the dynamic factor model to my data for forecasting but I'm getting this error. `'dk'` is a dataframe of stock index time series data. 
I'm doing the following:

```
dk_dfm = dk.loc['08-Nov-15':,'std_Volume':'std_IR']

mod = statsmodels.api.tsa.DynamicFactor(endog = dk_dfm, k_factors=1, factor_order=2, error_order=3)
```

till here it's getting processed.

```
dfm = mod.fit(method='newton', disp=False)
```

here i'm getting the error: **'object arrays are not supported'**

Comment: What's the `dtypes` of `dk_dfm`?  When `pandas` columns (Series) contain strings or dates or other items that aren't numbers, its `dtype` is `object`.  Even when converted to `numpy` arrays (with `values` or `to_numpy`) they still have that dtype.  Many numerical operations don't with non-numeric data.

Comment: dk_dfm is made up of "float" data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
dk_dfm = dk.loc['08-Nov-15':,'std_Volume':'std_IR'].values
```

to get a numpy array, I have no experience with statsmodels but this solution tends to work for this error 
EDIT: The fix that worked was upgrading to version 0.10rc2

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Can u suggest something else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using statsmodels version 0.9.0?

Comment: Yes. It's version 0.9.0

Comment: It appears to be a bug in statsmodels, from [this discussion](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5512)  and upgrading to version 0.10rc2 should fix it

Comment: So, after upgrading the package and running this once again, I am getting this error: "Non-positive-definite forecast error covariance matrix encountered at period 3"

Comment: That's beyond me, you can ask the developers of this package for help [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/)